# Liferay : Can we set WebKeys.VM_VARIABLES from portlet and access it from theme?

Tags: liferay, velocity

I have a liferay hook where I am setting VM variables to be accessed by the theme. Those are working nicely. However, I need to send variabels from my portlet to the theme as well. Is that possible with VM Variables? Or do I need to use a different technique?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your variable inside **request scope** which is accessible inside theme.

Inside theme you can access it like this

```
$request.getParameter("parameter")
```

HTH

Comment: What if the variables are same as the one present in the hook ?

Comment: you can directly use that variable in vm file i.e inside portal_normal.vm use like this $variableName